# Reopening the application freshly through appium java script for Next Testcase

Tags: android, junit, appium

I run appium java script successfully.But problem is ,My Application starts with sign in page.after signing in, i Could automate some test cases.But I want to come again from sign in page through script to run next test case.
.How can I close the app and also from background mode and reopen applciation without re-installing app again?because testcases should not depend each other

```
public class AppTest {
    
    private static RemoteWebDriver driver;
      
    @BeforeClass
    public static void initSimulator() throws MalformedURLException
    {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");            
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.1");           
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");                
            capabilities.setCapability("app", "D:\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\\sdk\\platform-tools\\Yr.apk");    
            capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.you.android");                   
            capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", "com.yr.sts.SplashActivity");                  
            capabilities.setCapability("app_wait_activity",".MainActivity");
            
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                capabilities);
          
            System.out.println("App Launched");
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void quitDriver() 
    {
       driver.quit();
       System.out.println("Driver has been Quit");
    }

    @Test
    public void sign_in_Click() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        WebElement sign_button = driver.findElement(By.name("Sign-in"));
        sign_button.click();
        WebElement usr = driver.findElement(By.id("com.you.android:id/et_login_email_or_mobile"));
        usr.sendKeys("hello1@gmail.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement passwrd = driver.findElement(By.id("com.you.android:id/et_login_pwd"));
        passwrd.sendKeys("123456789");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElementByName("Sign in").click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        assertTrue( true );
    }
    @Test
    public void second_sign_in_Click() throws InterruptedException 
    {    
        //HERE I WANT TO REOPEN THE APPLICATION WITH SIGN IN  AFTER CLOSING APP.BECAUSE IN 1st TESTCASE , I HAVE SIGNED IN.this is a 2nd test case    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change **@Beforeclass** and **@AfterClass** tags to **@Before** and **@After** respectively.

Right now your initSimulator() method will be called before every @Test, and quitDriver() method will be called after it. This way you will have new driver (with clear app) restarted every case.

So - as you see - in JUnit every test case is independent by default.

Why your problem occurred? From the [@BeforeClass docs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html):

> Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup
>   (like logging into a database). While this can compromise the
>   independence of tests, sometimes it is a necessary optimization.
>   Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes
>   it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class.

BTW, my initDriver() method looks like this, it is better way to handle quitting driver:

```
   public void quitDriver() {
        driver.closeApp();
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }
```

(it is static in your case)

Comment: sorry kiedys.I could not tick  your answer earlier to give 50 votes to you.Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: As I see in other thread: "You can offer as many bounties on a question as you want. However, only one bounty can be active on a question at a time." http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: so you can add a bounty to the question again I guess